# I want my action to be called in the object controller every time the esc_key is pressed. .observes()

Tags: ember.js

I'm reading the Ember docs on the .observes() method but I'm still confused as to how to use observes() to detect something like a keyDown.

So we're in an Object Controller for this example.

```
someAction: function() {
  console.log('This will be written in the console every time the esc_key has been pressed on this page. 
}.observes(the esc_key being pressed),
```

Answer (score 1):

`observes` watches properties in the model, not actions the user takes. Events, like keyDown, get tracked and handled by the view layer (which by convention has the same name as the template)

See the following link for more info:

http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/

Comment: Ember's solution seems a bit counter-productive to me, if I want the esc_key to handle an event in an action that handles a property in the controller, shouldn't that action be in the controller and not the view since that is also where the property is?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The View handles the browser events and triggers the controller actions. See the following - http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/

Comment: @IanSteffy That is incorrect. The view processes user events and the controllers performs business logic. To better understand this you might want to read about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)